# Android Studio deletes another app while running new

Tags: android, apk, project

I first created an app in Android Studio and completed it. Then i needed a second app for another purpose that would look almost identical to the first one but with minor changes. I therefore took a copy of the whole first app's project folder and pasted it in another spot. I did some renaming of the package names and other changes and ran the apk to the phone from Android Studio. Its working fine, but when i run this new apk it deletes the first app i created on the phone, even though their names is not the same

Question is, what do i need to change in my project for Android Studio to know that these are two different apps, and it should not delete app 1 when i run app 2?

Comment: package name must be diffrent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package name must be different for both the apps, 
make sure you are changing package name in manifest xml as well as the build.gradle file

Comment: It was in the build-gradle file i had missed changing the applicationId entry to another one.